# How do I execute .js files locally in my browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Hello i was wondering how i can type a javascript game on textmate with my mac and have just a regular .js file but than take the .js file and open it and have it run in chrome like if i have it say "Hello World!" than Hello World! would show up in chrome.

An example of what I'm after is in this video: http://vimeo.com/105955605

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Around 1:51 in the video, notice how she puts a `<script>` tag in there?  The way it works is like this:

Create an html file (that's just a text file with a `.html` ending) somewhere on your computer.  In the same folder that you put `index.html`, put a javascript file (that's just a textfile with a `.js` ending - let's call it `game.js`).  Then, in your `index.html` file, put some html that includes the script tag with `game.js`, like Mary did in the video.  `index.html` should look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Now, double click on that file in finder, and it should open it up in your browser.  To open up the console to see the output of your javascript code, hit Command-alt-j (those three buttons at the same time).

Good luck on your journey, hope it's as fun for you as it has been for me so far :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Google Chrome you can use the Chrome Dev Editor: https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor